# Is there any way to trim the end of a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

Is there any way to trim everything after a given character, let's say '_' . Is there any way to do that?
Example:

```
string ul = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog________ dog dog"
int ullocation = ul.find("_")
(code to remove everything after the underline using the int)
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: I can't make a substring for this, as it has to be the same variable. @BillLynch

Comment: `ul = ul.substr(...)`?

Comment: This last example on this page documenting `std::string::erase` does exactly what you want: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std:string::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), eg:

```cpp
string ul = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog________ dog dog";
string::size_type idx = ul.find("_");
if (idx != string::npos) ul.erase(idx);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/VTk35w)